# Vim markdown syntax highlighting prevent underscore interpretation

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I am using vim to edit my source code, but the syntax highlighting is doing one particular thing that is unfortunate.  Per ordinary markdown notation, the underscore character ordinarily does a particular thing, and the syntax is highlighted appropriately.  However, I am also using MathJax with my markdown (I'm specifically using [reveal-md](https://github.com/webpro/reveal-md)).  When my text is surrounded by a pair of double dollarsigns `$$`, the underscore does *not* mean what my syntax highlighter thinks it means.  So, I'd like to disable just the underscore bits of the vim markdown syntax highlighter.  Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Note that I don't necessarily need to disable the _ bits only when text is in the dollar sign environment.  I'd be happy to just disable it altogether.